# Oracle sql tag every first duplicate with true and others with false

Tags: sql, oracle

Being a beginner in SQL oracle, I am working on a table `CATS` with 4 varchar2 fields `country`, `hair`, `color` and `firstItemFound`.
I am trying to edit a sql request so each time I hit a new tuple `name || country || color` , I add an attribute `'true'` if I did already find this tuple I add an attribute `'false'`.

I thought about this :

**step 1)** Update (select distinct name, country, color from cats) tmp_cats set firstItemFound = true;

**step 2)** Update cats set firstItemFound = false where firstItemFound is null;

But **1)** is not working because you can't update a non physical view. Does there is any work around ? Is it possible to do it in one operation instead of two ?

Here is my table values (firstItemFound column has null values) :

```
NAME   |COUNTRY   |COLOR  |
-------|----------|-------|
France |Shorthair |Red    |
Brazil |Longhair  |Yellow |
France |Shorthair |Red    |
France |Longhair  |Brown  |
France |Longhair  |Black  |
Brazil |Longhair  |Yellow |
Brazil |Longhair  |Black  |
Brazil |Longhair  |Brown  |
Brazil |Longhair  |Yellow |
```

Here is my wanted result :

```
country    hair       color    firstItemFound
---------------------------------------------
France   Shorthair     Red      true
France   Shorthair     Red      false
France   Longhair     Brown     true
France   Longhair     Black     true
Brazil   Longhair     Yellow    true
Brazil   Longhair     Yellow    false
Brazil   Longhair     Yellow    false
Brazil   Longhair     Black     true
Brazil   Longhair     Brown     true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `row_number` for making 1st item true

```
select *,case when rn=1 then true else false end as firstItemFound  from 
(select country,hair,colur, row_number() 
over(partition by country,hair,colur order by country) rn from t
) t
```

or you can use cte expression

```
with t as (
select * from 
(
select 'France' as country  ,'Shorthair' as hair,'Red' as colur from dual
union all 
select 'Brazil','Longhair','Yellow' from dual
union all
select 'France' ,'Shorthair','Red' from dual

)  
) , t2 as
(
select country,hair,colur, row_number() 
over(partition by country,hair,colur order by country) rn from t

)select t2.*, case when rn=1 then 'true' else 'false' end as firstItemFound  from t2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=65146824ed31dbbc6daa40676220cdf8

```
COUNTRY     HAIR    COLUR   RN  FIRSTITEMFOUND
Brazil  Longhair    Yellow  1   true
France  Shorthair   Red     1   true
France  Shorthair   Red     2   false
```

Comment: sorry but I do not understand at all how this request works

Comment: @Logan Wlv select ns_tab2.*,case when rn=1 then 'true' else 'false' end as firstItemFound  from 
(select name,country,color, row_number() 
over(partition by name,country,color order by name) rn from ns_tab2
) ns_tab2;  this is corrected

Comment: but your output is coming to be from descending to ascending

Comment: Brazil Longhair Black 1 true
Brazil Longhair Brown 1 true
Brazil Longhair Yellow 1 true
Brazil Longhair Yellow 2 false
Brazil Longhair Yellow 3 false
France Longhair Black 1 true
France Longhair Brown 1 true
France Shorthair Red 1 true
France Shorthair Red 2 false

Comment: Yeah got it thank you I tested it, it works but could you explain the "over(partition .." part please ?

Comment: @LoganWlv [About analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You may use dense_rank by including and extra column such as `id` for ordering :

```
with t(id,country,hair,colour) as
(
 select 1,'France', 'Shorthair', 'Red' from dual union all
 select 2,'Brazil', 'Longhair', 'Yellow' from dual union all
 select 3,'France', 'Shorthair', 'Red' from dual
)
 select country,hair,colour, 
        (case when ( dense_rank() over (partition by country,hair,colour order by id) = 1 ) 
             then 'true'
             else 'false'
        end) as firstItemFound          
   from t 
  order by id;

COUNTRY HAIR       COLOUR   FIRSTITEMFOUND
France  Shorthair   Red         true
Brazil  Longhair    Yellow      true
France  Shorthair   Red         false
```